# Is there a standard way to instantiate class in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Can I do something like this:

```
$person = $this->load->library('person');
$person->name = 'John';
```

I don't need to use it in this way:

```
$this->person->name = 'John';
```

Is there any standard way to reference instance of object?

Comment: This depends on what is in the person library

Comment: Yes. The time you to to write the question would be more than enough to try it yourself.

Comment: `$this->person` Is the only standard way to get access to instance of `Person` Class in CI. using `$person` directly in OOP, needs `$person` to defined as global variable.